# How to make midori accept letsencrypt.org certificates?

Tags: apache2, midori, letsencrypt

I have a `dokuwiki` instance served by `apache2` on port 446 for HTTP and HTTPS access. Both HTTP and HTTPS access work fine with `firefox`. On `midori` HTTPS fails due to `An unexpected TLS packet was received.`. I suspect missing CA entry, but I don't find an option in `midori` to add a CA. Maybe it uses an Ubuntu keyring?

I'm using `midori` 0.5.11 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Midori has stopped been developed. Switch to Epiphany (Web), similar to Midori and very light also.

```
sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser
```

You can also tweak it from Dconf-editor.

Comment: As of Feb 2021 Midori is still (or once again) in active development at https://gitlab.com/midori-web/midori-desktop, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_(web_browser) says it's been "revamped entirely", switching from WebKitGTK to Electron.  Epiphany uses WebKitGTK, so may perhaps give an experience more like the old Midori.

Answer (score 0):

`midori` seems to accept letsencrypt.org certificates, the webserver just wasn't configured correctly.